# Best practice to find one item in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, rest, sqlalchemy

is one of these optiona better over the other one? Is there a best practice for doing this? Please notice that I am interested to know what is the best practice, may not be any of these. Is it to use .one(), catch the exception and do something there? Is it better to get a None object and handle it with an if statement? Is there a better option?

**OPTION 1**

```py
session = self.Session()
try:
    user = session.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id).one()
    return user 
except (NoResultFound) as e:
    session.rollback()
    # Here I am actually hanlding this and returning a 404 not found
    self.handle_not_found()
except (SQLAlchemyError) as e:
    self.handle_internal_error()
finally:
    session.close()
```

**OPTION 2**

```py
session = self.Session()
try:
    user = session.query(User).filter(User.id == object_id).one_or_none()
    if user is None:
        # Here I am actually hanlding this and returning a 404 not found
        self.handle_not_found()
    else:
        return user
except (SQLAlchemyError) as e:
    self.handle_internal_error()
finally:
    session.close()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no best practice as such.  All the below functions differ in the way they throw exceptions. It really depends on the requirement. You can use:

- [`.one()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one)
- [`.first()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.first)
- [`.one_or_none()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one_or_none)

`one` will give you the only item, but raise exceptions for a query with zero or multiple results.

`first` will return the first result, or None if there are no results.

`one_or_none` raises an exception only if there are multiple results for the query. Otherwise it'll return the single result, or `None` if there were no results.

So, choose what you want exactly and then use the right one.

Comment: @Nahuel Please let me know if the answer helped or not?